# How to: Archive a Database

Tags: php, mysql, store, archive

Can someone tell me the different ways of archiving MySQL database information's ?
I want to save My database table for using it as an archive and store new information's in the first database It's like getting backup from my database . 
I want to know the best ways for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the best way to do this ?

Keep all the data in a single table.
Databases are intended to store data. Even more data than you an imagine.

Just add `date` field tho the table and you'll be able to filter out your records by month - you just need to learn a little SQL for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a `cron` job to periodically copy the info to an archive table(s) and then perform a delete on the working table. Beyond that its all application/requirements specific and you havent provided enough info to get into more detail.